# Solved ! Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected character SOAP API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, soap, savon

I'm trying to communicate with SOAP API `https://www.flussituristici.servizirl.it/Turismo5/app/ws/checkinV1?wsdl`
using Savon gem.

so far I've implemented following code:

```
  def client
    client = Savon.client(
      wsdl: "https://www.flussituristici.servizirl.it/Turismo5/app/ws/checkinV1?wsdl",
      host: "https://www.flussituristici.servizirl.it/Turismo5/app/ws/checkinV1",
      soap_header: { 'Authorization:' => "Basic #{Base64.strict_encode64("username: password")}"},
      log: true,
      pretty_print_xml: true
    )
    client.call(:invia_movimentazione, message: message, soap_action: '')
  end

  def message
    {
      movimenti:
      {
        codice: "S00352",
        prodotto: "XXXXX",
        movimento:
        [
          {
            data: "20190911",
            struttura:
              {
                apertura: "SI",
                camereoccupate: "10",
                cameredisponibili: "16",
                lettidisponibili: "34"
              }
          },
          {
            data: "20190911",
            struttura:
            {
              apertura: "SI",
              camereoccupate: "9",
              cameredisponibili: "16",
              lettidisponibili: "34"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  end
```

but i'm getting following error response:

```
D, [2019-09-11T06:45:28.544608 #12024] DEBUG -- : HTTPI /peer GET request to www.flussituristici.servizirl.it (net_http)
I, [2019-09-11T06:45:29.557382 #12024]  INFO -- : SOAP request: https://www.flussituristici.servizirl.it/Turismo5/app/ws/checkinV1
I, [2019-09-11T06:45:29.562181 #12024]  INFO -- : SOAPAction: "", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 925
D, [2019-09-11T06:45:29.576008 #12024] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://checkin.ws.service.turismo5.gies.it/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <Authorization:>Basic TUk0OTg1231d01kTmNXKkp2N3I123</Authorization:>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <tns:inviaMovimentazione>
      <movimenti>
        <codice>S00352</codice>
        <prodotto>XXXXX</prodotto>
        <movimento>
          <data>20190911</data>
          <struttura>
            <apertura>SI</apertura>
            <camereoccupate>10</camereoccupate>
            <cameredisponibili>16</cameredisponibili>
            <lettidisponibili>34</lettidisponibili>
          </struttura>
        </movimento>
        <movimento>
          <data>20190911</data>
          <struttura>
            <apertura>SI</apertura>
            <camereoccupate>9</camereoccupate>
            <cameredisponibili>16</cameredisponibili>
            <lettidisponibili>34</lettidisponibili>
          </struttura>
        </movimento>
      </movimenti>
    </tns:inviaMovimentazione>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>

D, [2019-09-11T06:45:29.580471 #12024] DEBUG -- : HTTPI /peer POST request to www.flussituristici.servizirl.it (net_http)
I, [2019-09-11T06:45:30.455910 #12024]  INFO -- : SOAP response (status 500)
D, [2019-09-11T06:45:30.457178 #12024] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected character '&gt;' (code 62) (expected a name start character)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,289]</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Savon::SOAPFault: (soap:Client) Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected character '>' (code 62) (expected a name start character)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,289]
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/savon-2.11.2/lib/savon/response.rb:85:in `raise_soap_and_http_errors!'
```

what is this error indicating? how can I debug it?

**UPDATE:**
There was an issue when initializing the Savon client, the documentation said I need to send a Base43 encoded "username": "password" like i did previously but just sending the username & password as below worked fine.

```
def client
  client = Savon.client(
      wsdl: END_POINT,
      basic_auth: ["username", "password"],
      log: true,
      pretty_print_xml: true
    )
  client.call(:invia_movimentazione, message: message, soap_action: '')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In a first step I use [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org) to create a valid request.
If I can get this work then I'm creating the identical request with Savon.
For debugging you should include `log_level: :debug`when you create your client.

From your question it looks like there is an oddity with the Authorization tag. There is a colon in the tag which usually splits a namespace from the identifier.

Instead of `<Authorization:>` I'd expect something like `<Authorization:identifier>`.

Comment: thanks, I played around with the authorization as well after posting question :D